# How do I assign a single Keystroke to multiple items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Skyrim is great during the gameplay but I dont like the menus at all. The problem is there are scenarios where I need to switch whole sets of armor, rings, necklaces and weapons very quickly.

For eg, I start quests with sneaking around, for that I use the nightingale armor and use detect life spell + soul trap elven dagger. Now, when a tough guy / boss comes in the way then I need to switch to heavy steel armor, necklace for block, shield and a strong sword. Then I need to switch back.

This involves so much menu navigation that I am starting to hate it. It would be superb if I could assign keys to scenarios like:

1. Assassin - light armor + blade
2. Warrior - heavy armor + one handed combat
3. Sharp shooter - light armor + bow + arrows
4. Mage - magica regen apparel + spells
5. Thief - muffle apparel + blade + lockpick/pickpocket ring/necklace
6. Business man - stuff to increase speech craft and price discount etc etc etc

God! Is it just me or it is such a pain to switch between these items in-game. All because I like efficient gameplay.

I know the game doesnt support this (I know about the Q - # shortcuts) but perhaps there are scripts or mods that allow assigning a keystroke to multiple items (apparel, weapons, spells, shouts, powers)?

Comment: I don't know of any mods for that yet, but that's a VERY common complaint so I'm sure it will only be a matter of time until a few mods come out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A macro program like [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is what you're looking for.

Since skyrim has a consolified interface, almost any action can be done with keystrokes alone.

The trick is to use the favorites menu, and walk trough it while selecting the things you want.

A macro I have for example is:

- <kbd>q</kbd> opens quick menu
- <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> moves to top of list (number of items in list.)
- <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>equips or unequips an unrelated weapon and shield
- the desired weapon is has a known state (unequiped)
- <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> moves to wapon and equips it.
- <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> moves to shield and equips it.
- <kbd>q</kbd> closes quick menu.

It isn't instant or very quick, but it saves a lot of time.

However, this setup is fragile and basically only works when all items of the Quick menu have consistent names.

Comment: It's sometimes possible for ahk to read the text from a program's window. I'm guessing this isn't possible with skyrim?

Comment: I didn't investigate that. (also, I use a (first-gen) Logitech G15 keyboard, which has macro functionality build in.)

Comment: this sound promising, but the items change very often. Sounds like a lot of pain and wouldnt I need to quit the game every time i wanted to change it?

Comment: This should also be possible via the in-game console.. perhaps a script in an external text file can be called..? any idea where I can find a list of commands? EDIT: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)

Comment: @VaibhavGarg if you consistently (re)name your items while enchanting you can ensure a sane order of the favorites menu.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly there is no way to do it yet.
Like @Fambida wrote, lets pray for a mod that bethesda does not banish.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the group function in SkyUI and assign a group to a key in the mod configuration menu.

Besides SkyUI really helps with inventory management in general.

Comment: Can you describe further how do to this?